# CheckboxList selections cleared on linkbutton click (despite postback check)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, checkboxlist

How are checkbox properties retrieved before they are cleared?

I'd like to count the number of checked boxes after clicking "Go!". Instead, after clicking, the boxes (even those that default to selected) are cleared and the count is zero.

Do I need another way of protecting the values from postback?

[image: Page Load] 
→ 
[image: After "Go!"]

***.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="LunaIntraDB.sandbox" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.master" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/SiteMaster.master" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" ID="HeadContentContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" ID="MainContentContent" runat="server">

<asp:CheckBoxList ID="aCheckBoxList" runat="server" >
  <asp:ListItem Value="DontCheck" runat="server">1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="blah" Selected="True" runat="server">2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="goButton" runat="server" Text="Go!" onclick="Clicked" />

</asp:Content>
```

***.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace LunaIntraDB
{

    public partial class sandbox : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                debugPrint("Load,beforeAdd");
                aCheckBoxList.Items.Add("Added 1");
                aCheckBoxList.Items.Add("Added 2");
                aCheckBoxList.Items.Add("Added 3");
                aCheckBoxList.Items[4].Selected = true;
                debugPrint("Load,addedItems");

            } else {
                debugPrint("PostBack");
            }
        }

        protected void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            debugPrint("Button push");
        }

        /* Print Selected index and a count of selected checkboxes */
        protected void debugPrint(String where) {
            String count = aCheckBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(n => n.Selected).ToList().Count.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(where +": "+ aCheckBoxList.SelectedIndex.ToString() + " =>" + count + "/"+ aCheckBoxList.Items.Count.ToString()  );
        }
    }
}
```

**Console output**

> [0:] Load,beforeAdd: 1 =>1/2
>
> [0:] Load,addedItems: 1 =>2/5
>
> // check a bunch and click "Go!"
>
> [0:] PostBack: -1 =>0/5
>
> [0:] Button push: -1 =>0/5

**Mono version**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.3 (tarball Sun Sep 22 20:38:43 UTC 2013) Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Comment: "It could be a bug, but I am classifying it as an oddity. As far as I have found out in the MS specifications, the checkbox state of dynamic checkbox list controls is set during the prerender phase.  ... While the state is not directly available in the controls, it is available in the viewstate, and can be accessed in the Request collection."

http://www.strawberryfin.co.uk/blog/2012/08/22/dealing-with-dynamic-checkboxlists-losing-their-state-after-postback/

**but I thought my example is not necessary dynamic, with asp:ListItems on the .aspx page (?)**

Comment: This code works as expected in MS .NET

Comment: there are a couple of pull requests in github's mono repo around fixing ASP.NET's checkbox issues, you could check if they fix your bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Will's answer in on the right track, it isn't conclusive of the entire issue.

For example, when a CheckBoxList is inside of Repeater control, the ClientID has a different format to indicate the CheckBoxList position inside the Repeater.

It's also safe to say that we don't really want to handle this issue for every use of a CheckBoxList, so I've created a custom control that extends the CheckBoxList.OnLoad event to resolve the issue outline above.

```
namespace YOURNAMESPACE.Controls
{
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using WebControls = System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public class CheckBoxList : WebControls.CheckBoxList
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" && Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null) {

                string cblFormID = Regex.Replace(ClientID, @"_\d+$", String.Empty).Replace("_", "$");

                int i = 0;
                foreach (WebControls.ListItem item in Items)
                    item.Selected = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[cblFormID + "$" + i++] == item.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Taken from http://www.strawberryfin.co.uk/blog/2012/08/22/dealing-with-dynamic-checkboxlists-losing-their-state-after-postback/

**In Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e):**

```
setCheckBoxStates (aCheckBoxList);
```

**elsewhere**

```
public static void setCheckBoxStates(CheckBoxList cbl)
        {
            // if we are postback and using mono
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST"  && Type.GetType("Mono.Runtime") != null)
            {
                string cblFormID = cbl.ClientID.Replace("_","$");
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item in cbl.Items)
                {
                    string itemSelected = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[cblFormID + "$" + i];
                    if (itemSelected != null && itemSelected != String.Empty)
                        ((ListItem)item).Selected = true;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try `EnableViewState="True"` property at @page as follow:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="LunaIntraDB.sandbox" 
MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.master" 
EnableViewState="True"
%>
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. ...
and if I set EnableViewState to false, there is a index out of bounds error. (aCheckBoxList is smaller than expected because the aspx added checkboxes are lost?)

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Index is less than 0 or more than or equal to the list count. Parameter name: index 4

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.